# Keras lambda function dot product mistmatch

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I have the following function:

```
def transpose_dot(vects):
    x, y = vects
    # <x,x> + <y,y> - 2<x,y>

    return K.dot(x, K.transpose(y))
```

When try to evaluate it with `keras` it works

```
x = K.variable(np.array(np_x))
y = K.variable(np.array(np_x))
obj = transpose_dot
objective_output = obj((x, y))
print('-----------------')
print (K.eval(objective_output))
```

result with:

```
[[ 1.  1.  1.  2.]
 [ 1.  2.  2.  4.]
 [ 1.  2.  2.  4.]
 [ 2.  4.  4.  8.]
```

**But**, when try to use it as function for `Lambda` layer it does not work.

```
np_x = [[1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [2, 2]]
features = np.array([np_x])
test_input = Input(shape=np.array(np_x).shape)
dot_layer= Lambda(transpose_dot, output_shape=(4,4))([test_input, test_input])
x = Model(inputs=test_input, outputs=dot_layer)
x.predict(features, batch_size=1)
```

Result with

```
self.fn() if output_subset is None else\
ValueError: Shape mismatch: x has 2 cols (and 4 rows) but y has 4 rows (and 2 cols)
Apply node that caused the error: Dot22(Reshape{2}.0, Reshape{2}.0)
Toposort index: 11
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, matrix)]
Inputs shapes: [(4, 2), (4, 2)]
Inputs strides: [(8, 4), (8, 4)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown']
Outputs clients: [[Reshape{4}(Dot22.0, MakeVector{dtype='int64'}.0)]]
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Edit:
Added output of the error message

Comment: What is the error message? You have a ) missing in the Lambda line...

Comment: @NassimBen, I added the error message, Basically it complains about the shape, but ` x has 2 cols (and 4 rows) but y has 4 rows (and 2 cols)`

Answer (score 0):

With the help from guys at https://github.com/fchollet/keras/ I found my mistake.
The function expect to get (n,m). But when using a Lambda function it expect to get (samples,n,m).